# Using the watch command with an argument that contains quotes

Tags: bash, unix, watch

I'm trying to get watch to work correct with commands that contain quotes, and the watch man page isn't very detailed about how quotes work. To give a concrete example, how can I run the following command inside of watch:

```
ps -ef | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'
```

I've tried:

```
watch "ps -ef | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'"
```

and

```
watch 'ps -ef | awk -F\' \' \'{print $2}\''
```

but neither of these works correctly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I guess you have to escape the `$` sign:

```
watch "ps -ef | awk -F' ' '{print \$2}'"
```

otherwise it would be interpreted by the shell which would result in an empty string (`""`) - i.e. `awk` would print the whole line.

Answer (score 12):

You could always put your command in a shell script, then "watch" the script.

Answer (score 3):

I just met a similar problem. After reading the [watch Man Page](http://ss64.com/bash/watch.html), I found a solution that could work, which is to concatenate strings in bash. The final command looked weird, such as:

```
watch "ps -ef | awk -F' ' '"'{print $2}'"'"
```

or

```
watch 'ps -ef | awk -F'"' ' '"'{print $2}'"'"
```