# Function using watch on command with command line arguments

Tags: linux, command-line, watch

I want to run `watch` on a command which uses an optional command line argument, like this:

```
function queue() {
    watch -n 10 'squeue -p ${1:-default} -o "%.8i" '
}
```

but the command-line argument isn't used, i.e. the default is only ever used.  I tried [escaping the `$` as per this answer](https://superuser.com/a/276706/152522) (e.g. `watch -n 10 'squeue -p \${1:-default} -o "%.8i" '`), but that didn't work either.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When things are in single quotes no variable expansion happens, try

```
function queue() {
    watch -n 10 "squeue -p ${1:-default} -o '%.8i'"
}
```

so the outer quotes are double, which will then do variable expansion within the string

Comment: This affords one to make a  "watch function" which watches user-made function with argument. I found that it is possible to make a watch function (queue() in this case) which runs watch and user-made function (squeue, in this case) which gets its own argument from watch function (queue()).